# Significance of Co-efficient of Variation

Tags: statistical-significance, coefficient-of-variation

**Is there a formula that is able to determine whether the difference between two co-efficients of variation is significant or if not is there a specific heuristic used to determine significance (i.e. cv<0.05)?**

I am curious of this because: I am trying to compare a data set with widely different means.  I want to see if the difference between co-efficient of variance between the two sets is significant in order to determine the importance of the behavior of a certain factor.

I have already consulted this forum (as well as [here](http://listserv.uga.edu/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind1212a&L=sas-l&H=1&P=1084/%22this%22)) but I have not found a clear answer.

Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by "the significance of a particular variable"?

Comment: I think you need to rectify your terminology, as currently it makes little sense. This may be a common terminology or approach in your substantive field, but I cannot really follow your request. Please do not comment, but instead edit your post to provide more information. What are the variables? What do you want to analyze? Why do you think you need the coefficient of variation? Give references. My feeling is that if you are measuring whether some things occur together, this is a log-linear analysis of some kind, and it has little to do with coefficients of variation.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I simplified the question so that the specific field of which this calculation is to be applied should not be an issue. However, I have also asked a question that goes more detailed into the problem. I would be interested on your insight on log-linear analysis, thank you. The question is found here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49334/co-efficient-of-variation-to-elimate-frequency-bias-in-vector

Comment: For the [lognormal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution), $\log(1+CV^2)$ estimates the geometric variance $\sigma^2$ and therefore you could try adapting tests of variance (such as F tests) in this case. The CV could also be considered a parameter in many cases and so can be tested using asymptotic maximum likelihood methods. There are always permutation tests. The larger point I am trying to make is that the right choice of test may depend on your probability model, as well as on the nature of the data and the reason for conducting the test in the first place.

Comment: Thank you whuber, for your input. I edited the question to address what type of data I am working with.